# Mysql Update Query To reset the column values to 25 chars where values are greater then 25 chars

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, updating

I need a Query to update all the values of a column "COMPANY_NAME" from table "Histroyhp" restricting to 25 Chars
Where already Data exists in the DB.

I need only first 25 chars from the existing Values.

Where my table is having 1000's of records few are already less than 25 chars and many are greater than 25 chars length.

Comment: Is the column declared as `varchar()` or `nvarchar()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes it is varchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`length()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) function to check the character count and [`left()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function to pick first 25 characters

```
update Histroyhp
set COMPANY_NAME = left(COMPANY_NAME,25)
where length(COMPANY_NAME) > 25
```

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid    Thanks a lot it worked form the query you provided

Comment: You don't actually need the length function, but it probably makes the query more efficient.